Customize Strapi v4 Left menu items with patch-package
I'm trying to customize the Strapi left menu by using patch-package, but I can't find how to apply the changes.
I'm using Strapi 4.24.2
First of all, I had the patch-package module and a script "postinstall: patch-package" in the package.json
Then I made some changes inside the "index-hDD1JNph.js" in the node_modules
After that I ran the command :

npx patch-package @strapi/admin

Finally, I ran

docker-compose build


docker-compose up

but I see no changes in the Strapi admin panel
package.json:
{
  "name": "heritage-cms",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "description": "A Strapi application",
  "scripts": {
    "develop": "strapi develop",
    "start": "strapi start",
    "build": "strapi build",
    "strapi": "strapi"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@_sh/strapi-plugin-ckeditor": "^2.1.1",
    "@strapi/plugin-color-picker": "^4.24.2",
    "@strapi/plugin-documentation": "4.24.2",
    "@strapi/plugin-i18n": "4.24.2",
    "@strapi/plugin-seo": "^1.9.8",
    "@strapi/plugin-users-permissions": "4.24.2",
    "@strapi/provider-upload-cloudinary": "^4.25.0",
    "@strapi/strapi": "4.24.2",
    "cloudinary": "^2.2.0",
    "mysql": "^2.18.1",
    "react": "^18.0.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.0.0",
    "react-is": "^18.3.1",
    "react-router-dom": "5.3.4",
    "strapi-gtm-module": "^0.0.5",
    "strapi-plugin-cookie-manager": "^1.2.4",
    "strapi-plugin-google-analytics": "^0.0.0",
    "strapi-plugin-populate-deep": "^3.0.1",
    "styled-components": "5.3.3"
  },
  "author": {
    "name": "A Strapi developer"
  },
  "strapi": {
    "uuid": "a7af0888-4778-46c2-9a6c-f1d1c2dffdb7"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=18.0.0 <=20.x.x",
    "npm": ">=6.0.0"
  },
  "license": "MIT"
}

Dockerfile:
FROM node:18-alpine3.18
# Installing libvips-dev for sharp Compatibility
RUN apk update && apk add --no-cache build-base gcc autoconf automake zlib-dev libpng-dev nasm bash vips-dev
ARG NODE_ENV=development
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}
WORKDIR /opt/
COPY package.json yarn.lock ./
RUN yarn config set network-timeout 600000 -g && yarn install

WORKDIR /opt/app
COPY . .
ENV PATH /opt/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
RUN chown -R node:node /opt/app
USER node
RUN ["yarn", "build"]
EXPOSE 1337
CMD ["yarn", "develop"]

docker-compose.yml:
services:
  heritage-cms:
    container_name: heritage-cms
    build: .
    env_file: .env
    environment:
      DATABASE_CLIENT: ${DATABASE_CLIENT}
      DATABASE_HOST: ${DATABASE_HOST}
      DATABASE_NAME: ${DATABASE_NAME}
      DATABASE_USERNAME: ${DATABASE_USERNAME}
      DATABASE_PORT: ${DATABASE_PORT}
      JWT_SECRET: ${JWT_SECRET}
      ADMIN_JWT_SECRET: ${ADMIN_JWT_SECRET}
      DATABASE_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      NODE_ENV: ${NODE_ENV}
    volumes:
      - ./config:/opt/app/config
      - ./src:/opt/app/src
      - ./package.json:/opt/package.json
      - ./yarn.lock:/opt/yarn.lock

      - ./.env:/opt/app/.env
      - ./public/uploads:/opt/app/public/uploads
    ports:
      - "1337:1337"
    networks:
      - heritage-cms
    depends_on:
      - heritage-cmsDB

  heritage-cmsDB:
    container_name: heritage-cmsDB
    platform: linux/amd64 #for platform error on Apple M1 chips
    env_file: .env
    image: mysql:8.3.0
    command: --default-authentication-plugin=mysql_native_password
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: ${DATABASE_PASSWORD}
      MYSQL_DATABASE: ${DATABASE_NAME}
    volumes:
      - ./mysql-init-scripts:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/heritage_dump
      - heritage-cms-data:/var/lib/mysql
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    networks:
      - heritage-cms

  heritage-cmsAdminer:
    container_name: heritage-cmsAdminer
    image: adminer
    ports:
      - "9090:8080"
    environment:
      - ADMINER_DEFAULT_SERVER=heritage-cmsDB
    networks:
      - heritage-cms
    depends_on:
      - heritage-cmsDB

volumes:
  heritage-cms-data:

networks:
  heritage-cms:
    name: Heritage-cms
    driver: bridge

